# iOS custom UITableView cell buttons

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, swipe

I would like that when the user swipes a table view cell, to display more than one editing button (he default is the delete button). Is it possible to put custom buttons in the `tableView:tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method ?

Comment: And would you be so kind and show me how ?!

Comment: You can create a button in programmatically instead of editingStyle

Comment: I know that but I want it to appear in the native style like the delete button appears. I know I could use a swipe gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Add Gesture recognizer to your class and in its selector try below things.

```
-(void)cellDidSwipeLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)_gestureRecognizer
{
     if(_gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
     {
         CGPoint swipeLocation = [_gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

            NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];


            UITableViewCell* swipedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
            YourCustomBtn *Btn = (YourCustomBtn *)[swipedCell viewWithTag:999];

            [self performAnimationOnObject:Btn forPoint:swipeLocation];
      }
}





-(void)performAnimationOnObject:(id)view forPoint:(CGPoint)point
    {
     CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        animation.delegate = self;
        animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(btn.superview.frame.size.width, btn.center.y)];
                animation.toValue = [NSValue
                                     valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(mainCleanFrame.origin.x, btn.center.y)];
                animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                btn.center = CGPointMake(btn.frame.origin.x, btn.center.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new library to implement swippable buttons which supports a variety of transitions and expandable buttons like iOS 8 mail app.

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

This library is compatible with all the different ways to create a UITableViewCell and its tested on iOS 5, iOS 6, iOS 7 and iOS 8.

[image]